# Citation in the body of the text

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibentry

I have tried to use `bibtex` and `bibentry`, but I didn't succeed. Does someone have an idea how I can cite the whole reference in the body of the text, repeating or not the list of references in the end?

Here is the example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
    @book{example,
        author = "John",
        title = "The book's title",
        year = "2013",
        publisher = "Cambridge",
    }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  % bibliography package

\usepackage{bibentry}         %  full citation in the body of the text (turn off natbib if use it)

\nobibliography*                   % no bib at the end


\begin{document}

This would be the complete citation

\bibentry{example}

And this would be just the regular citation: \cite{example}


\bibliography{mybib.bib}

\bibliographystyle{apa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without an example or a piece of code is almost imposible to help you. Please add a MWE (Minimal Working Example) for illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two errors in your MWE.

1. `\bibliography{mybib.bib}` should be `\bibliography{mybib}` otherwise BibTeX looks for the file `mybib.bib.bib` instead of `mybib.bib`.
2. `\bibliographystyle{apa}` should be `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`. The bibliography style `apa.bst` is not compatible with `bibentry`.

So, delete your `.aux` and `.bbl` file, and retry with the following MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
    @book{example,
        author = "John",
        title = "The book's title",
        year = "2013",
        publisher = "Cambridge",
    }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  % bibliography package

\usepackage{bibentry}         %  full citation in the body of the text (turn off natbib if use it)

\nobibliography*                   % no bib at the end


\begin{document}

This would be the complete citation

\bibentry{example}

And this would be just the regular citation: \cite{example}


\bibliography{mybib}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]