# Citation in the body of the text without references section showing up

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibentry

I want to have the whole reference in the body of the text or in other words in-text citation. The solution to this problem has been given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150020/citation-in-the-body-of-the-text). However, the code is set up there such that there is also a reference section at the end. I don't want that. I only want the citations spelled out in the body itself and no references section at the end. Can it be done? How should I do it. Consider the code discussed [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150020/citation-in-the-body-of-the-text) itself as an example to try out the solution.

**Edit:** If there is any other method to get the full references spelled out within the body of the text directly from the bibtex entries but without invoking `\bibentry`, that'll also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `\nobibliography` if the bibliography shouldn't be printed:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
    @book{example,
        author = "John",
        title = "The book's title",
        year = "2013",
        publisher = "Cambridge",
    }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  % bibliography package

\usepackage{bibentry}         %  full citation in the body of the text (turn off natbib if use it)

\nobibliography*                   % no bib at the end


\begin{document}

This would be the complete citation

\bibentry{example}

And this would be just the regular citation: \cite{example}


\nobibliography{mybib}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

An alternative is to use biblatex + biber and the `\fullcite` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{document}

This would be the complete citation

\fullcite{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]